# Error while uploading image on dropbox

Tags: iphone, ios, dropbox

I'm developing an IPhone app were I need to upload image in a folder.I'm taking image from saved photo album and saving it in folder.I want to upload that image but I'm getting error.

Here is my code

```
NSMutableArray *array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSString *folderName;
if (metadata.isDirectory) {
    NSLog(@"Folder '%@' contains:", metadata.path);
    for (DBMetadata *file in metadata.contents)
    {
        [array addObject:file.filename];
        NSLog(@"\t%@", file.filename);
    }

    folderName=[array objectAtIndex:0];
}

NSString  *pngImagePath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",imageName.text]];
[data writeToFile:pngImagePath atomically:YES];

[[self restClient]uploadFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",imageName.text] toPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@",folderName]withParentRev:nil fromPath:pngImagePath];
```

I'm getting below error

```
File upload failed with error - Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain
Code=-1021 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain
error -1021.)" UserInfo=0x68d0c70 {destinationPath=/sonal/abc.png,
sourcePath=/Users/bcod/Library/Application Support/iPhone
Simulator/5.0/Applications/44555D9C-422E-45FC-B392-F74275B16378/Documents/abc.png}
```

I'm also getting following warning

```
[WARNING] DropboxSDK: error making request to
/1/files_put/dropbox/apple/app.png
```

Please anyone can tell me why am I getting this error

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you using sandbox in dropbox or production problem occur?

Comment: I'm using full dropbox

Answer (score 0):

Check the destination path.. it seems the issue is at server not able to find the destination folder

and 

also check the image size. Large file might be causing it to exhaust the request. Try with the smaller images

Comment: I tried checking both but still I'm getting same error

Comment: path needs to be current metadata path which u get in the loadedMetadata of the delegate and not the simple one u gave

Comment: i tried doing that but still same problem

Comment: I am also facing the same problem . Had you solved this problem? So please share it.